# delete multiple objects which are inside array in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

Very new to Apex and never touched java, basically what I am trying to do is delete all records then insert records inside multiple custom objects. Bellow is my code for just the deleting part but I have no idea how to get this working. Once I know how to get it working I can then put it inside a lop etc I just need the basics running first.

```
List<String> myList = new List<String> {'More_Info_Request__c'};

String foo = myList.get(0);

List<More_Info_Request__c> existing = [SELECT Id From :foo ];
delete existing;
```

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future **me** or future **human** this is how I fixed it:

```
List<String> objectNames = new List<String> {'More_Info_Request__c', 'Object1__c', 'Object2__c'};

for (String objectName : objectNames) {
    List<SObject> existing = Database.query('select id from ' + objectName);
    delete existing;
}
```

Comment: Using query in a loop is a bad decision! This link will be very helpful as long as you have just started with apex:https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices Are you using class or it is inside of a some trigger?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov is right, is better to store all the Sobjects in a list and delete the list